# Accessing abstract method implementation from abstract interface

Tags: java

My application is dependent on another applications abstract method implementation. I want help in how to access the implementation of that abstract method as the other application is only exposing us the Abstract interface which has the method definition.

So, my question is how to access the implementation of the abstract method, present in the abstract class. Do we have to use reflection for this ?

Comment: You want to call that method from derived class? If yes, just use `super` keyword, which points to the parent of extendend class

Comment: @MaciejTreder : No, i want to access the implementation in a class which is not a subclass of that abstract class.

Comment: So you need to use reflection.

Comment: Can you provide some pseudo-code to showcase your scenario, the structure of the classes, a bit? It is not that clear and it is also hard to give a precise answer other than just *'use technique xy'*. However currently it sounds like you need to use **reflection**. With **super** you can such a method and with reflection you are be able to edit some stuff of it at runtime. In general an extending class is not allowed to change code of its super class, that somehow breaks the inheritance concept. For example what if other classes also extend from that class etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but you'll need to instantiate a class that extends the abstract class.

```
Method m = AbstractClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("MethodName", Integer.class);
m.setAccessible(true);
m.invoke(new InstanceOfAbstractClass(),"parameter");
```

This is useful just if you need to access a private method of the abstract class. If this is not the case, you'll need to call the method from the child instance.